# Python and uvicorn problem server_header_factory

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to run a fastapi application with uvicorn, previously it was working perfectly fine, but now when I run

```
poetry run uvicorn app.rest_app:app
```

It raises an error:

```
TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_header_factory'
```

Uvicorn version is 0.23.2 and fastapi==0.103.2

Comment: What is the complete stack trace? Start by digging into why that parameter is being added and where it's being called; there is no `server_header_factory` defined in uvicorn/fastapi/starlette as far as I can tell from GitHub currently.